# locking a single field for exclusive access in mariadb

Tags: php, mariadb

I am running a web application in PHP, using mariadb as the database. Various independent scripts need to allocate a unique sequential sequence number (an invoice number), on completion of tasks performed for customers. Even though the invoices are different in nature and format, and in when and how they are generated, the managers want a common numbering system to show up in the accounting. I have a system parameters table and the next available invoice number is a field therein.

I need for each independent script to be able to allocate the next available invoice number while locking out other scripts trying to do the same thing. While still locked, the number is then incremented for the next process in line.  The primary goal is to avoid duplicate numbers without creating a bottleneck. The secondary goal is to avoid wasting numbers by skipping some.

It would be ideal to be able to lock the field, though just locking the table would be sufficient most of the time.  The number of allocations over time is not huge, though it could pick up in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan A:  Simply use `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Since you want a single stream of ids, you must have a single table where that `id` is generated.  That is not that much impact to worry about.  Caveat:  In a multi-master (incl. Galera / Group Replication), environment, `AUTO_INCREMENT` values are not consecutive.  Caveat:  Try to avoid `INSERT IGNORE`, `REPLACE`, IODKU and other commands that *may* burn ids.

Plan B:  Have a table dedicated just to this sequence number task.  Write a Stored Function to get the 'next' number.  *Call it in its own transaction.*  This will minimize the impact on other activities.

Both of the above avoid dup ids.  However, you cannot prevent skipped numbers.  Still, there are some things to do to avoid skipping numbers.  Minimize the need for `ROLLBACK`.  If you do `ROLLBACK`, you should probably apply the lost id to a "voided" invoice.  This might keep the Accountants and Auditors happier.

Another issue:  If you are using Replication, you cannot guarantee that the numbers will show up on the Slaves monotonically.  This is because grabbing an id is early in processing, but replication occurs in `COMMIT` order.

I vote for Plan B (which may include an `AUTO_INCREMENT` under the covers).  It gives you a centralized place to make the next change that the managers will ask for.

Comment: Thanks for the auto_increment idea. I will have to use B. The problem is that the invoice numbers are used in a record that has all kinds of transactions in it, and most of them do not have invoice numbers.  So that would be a bunch of wasted IDs.  But with a dedicated record containing no other fields, plan B does not have that issue.

Comment: Clarification: I am going to use both, B with auto_increment